# Skrollr constants in stylesheet?

Tags: css, skrollr

im trying to use the constants is combination with the stylesheet plugin but it doesnt work for some reason, heres what i did:

index.html

```
skrollr.init({
    constants: {
        scene2: 1200,
        scene3: 4000,
        scene4: 5000
    }
        });
```

skrollr.css

```
@-skrollr-keyframes background {
0 {background-color: white}
scene2-0 {background-color: white}
scene2-200 {background-color: red}
```

}

if i use the right values instead of the constants it works fine, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
_scene2-0 {background-color: white}
_scene2-200 {background-color: red}
```